# Checked bag transfer at Zurich

Tags: luggage, airport-transfer

Flying to Milan via Zurich on UA52: is 1hour enough for checked bag transfer?

Comment: Are both flights on the same ticket?

Answer (score 3):

If both flights are on the same ticket, then the airline thinks it’s enough.

You will have to go through immigration (passport control), and in the meantime your checked luggage will be transferred to the onward flight.

In normal circumstances (I.e. no delay on the first flight), this should be enough time.

If there are any delays, it’s possible that either you and/or your bags will miss the flight and will take the next one (the airline will rebook you on the next available flight). If you make the flight but not your bags you will have the option of either waiting for your bags in Milan or have them delivered to your hotel or other place you will be staying, though that can take a few hours or even happen on the next day. In any case get in touch with the airline’s luggage services before leaving the baggage claim area if there’s any issue.

If the flights are on separate tickets, it’s virtually impossible: you would need to go through immigration, claim your bags, go through customs, go the departures area and check-in or drop bags for your next flight before that flight’s check-in deadline. Not going to happen.

Comment: do you really go through Swiss immigration on flights connecting in Zurich?  I don’t remember doing this but that was pre-pandemic.

Comment: @ZeroTheHero depends on where you are arriving from and connecting to. Here OP connects to Milan, which like Zurich is in Schengen, so will need to go through passport control to enter the Schengen Area. If the connection was to another non-Schengen country there would not be any immigration checks.

Comment: yes you’re right I must remember incorrectly.  I remember (for various reasons) NOT going through Swiss customs but that must have been before Switzerland joined Schengen.  What has changed recently is this new  “far” terminal with the train in between.